# Which is more efficient Dependent component or subcomponent and what to use when

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am using dagger2 in my application. I am confused which one is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using dependent component you can access the limited dependencies which are declared downstream in app level component

On the other hand, subcomponent will give access to all dependencies of app level component.